# Why aren't train headlights brighter?

Tags: optics, popular-science

I suspect a valid scientific, physics answer for this question, because I'd venture that train, insurance companies would've calculated and contemplated this question.

Yet the train headlights at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TY9Kdj5PJI don't appear to brighten/illuminate sufficiently far ahead. If an obstacle or hindrance were in front, then wouldn't the limited range of the headlights prevent a safe stop?

Also, as can be seen at the 8:15 mark, the train's lights don't corner or turn together with the train. Why not? Wouldn't they befit and help such a train?

Shouldn't such heavy, menacing trains be equipped with headlights of the 'lumens' resembling http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPKy1KAz8OM and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWS30yHBuLQ *(same car and driver)*, how gleaming so ever it is for a car?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably impossible to illuminate most targets in time for a heavy freight train to stop. The lights are more to warn people on/near the tracks that the train is coming.

On most high speed trains (European/Japanese not American defn) driver can't even see signals in time and so has to rely on electronic readouts in the cab.

Given that a major design challenge of the cab is to make a windshield that can survive hitting a stone at 300km/h it would seem to make sense not to have a window (or a driver) at all.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.